# How to get data from API google?

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, google-play-games, google-api-client

I have `access_token` and now to try get fata from Google API using this sample:

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/details/get

I try to get data executing query to this URL:

https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/edits/editId

```
$curl = new Curl();
    $curl->get('https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/com.shazam.android&access_token='.$_SESSION['access_token']["access_token"]);
```

Where `$_SESSION['access_token']["access_token"]` is `access_token`

As a result I get message: `Error: 404: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

How to get information from API?

This is full URL request, it does not work:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/com.shazam.android/edits/1?access_token=ya29.Ci-5Azg5JoBiESM5cEzM3TQrP3SXHAFirFg0f-Fj83PxtrtINWQDe2L-3f5wP7oAtQ

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission"
 }
}
```

Full code is:

```
// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secretes.json you downloaded from the developer console.
$client = new Google_Client();

$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    // Set the access token on the client.
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);


    $curl = new Curl();
    $curl->get('https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/com.shazam.android/edits/1/&access_token='.$_SESSION['access_token']["access_token"]);

    if ($curl->error) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $curl->errorCode . ': ' . $curl->errorMessage . "\n";
    } else {
        echo 'Response:' . "\n";
        var_dump($curl->response);
    }

    // Create an authorized analytics service object.
    //$analytics = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

    // Get the first view (profile) id for the authorized user.
    //$profile = getFirstProfileId($analytics);

    // Get the results from the Core Reporting API and print the results.
    //$results = getResults($analytics, $profile);
    //printResults($results);
} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/play/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . $redirect_uri);
}
```

After getting `access_token` I try to make Curl request:

```
 $curl = new Curl();
        $curl->get('https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v1/applications/com.shazam.android/edits/1/&access_token='.$_SESSION['access_token']["access_token"]);
```

Comment: your get request is missing the last to parameters from the request  "edits/editId" https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/get

Comment: What should this parameter content?

Comment: it might if you format it correctly as a get request  ? != &

Comment: I updated question with a right query

Comment: Insufficient Permission tells you what the problem is then the user you are authenticating with does not have access to see that.

Comment: Okay I will post all code

Comment: Also `Google Play Android Developer API` is active

Comment: The user you have authenticated with does not have access to see that information.  This is not a project issue probably don't have access to com.shazam.android edit for edit id nr 1.

Comment: From where I can get `editId`? Whats is?

Comment: @Gagama Did you ever found the `editId`? I'm also wondering where i can found this

Answer (score 0):

Well, another possible caused of error `403 or Insufficient Permission` is that the scope that you are using is incorrect or you have not requested the scopes you need when you retrieved your access token. So try to double check the scope that you are using and enable all the API in the Dev Console that you are using.

You can check which scopes you have requested by passing your access_token to this endpoint:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

For more information, check the solution in these related SO question if it can help you.

- [Permission issue Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432825/permission-issue-google-play)
- [Google API 'Insufficient Permission'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970917/why-is-google-calendar-api-oauth2-responding-with-insufficient-permission)