# Google API 'Purchases.products: get' return 401 ERROR all of a sudden

Tags: google-api, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-oauth, google-authentication

[Purchases.products: get](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get) had been working well till 2 weeks ago. However, it starts returning Error suddenly. (I didn't change any options)

It can still refresh token through `POST` request to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` with (`grant_type`, `client_id`, `client_secret`, `refresh_token`) but with the access-token returned, `403` Error happen like the below.

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "androidpublisher",
                "reason": "permissionDenied",
                "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
            }
        ],
        "code": 401,
        "message": "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."
    }
}
```

This is google dashboard representing error rate for `Purchases.products: get`

[image]

I found [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24432825/permission-issue-google-play) but it is still not working.

---------- EDIT ----------

I want to describe more detail. I don't know if it is right way because I am actually just fixing Legacy system someone did.

The process above(refreshing token and requesting purchase info) is done in server-side. It is for server-side to verify if the purchase-information APP send is correct.

When APP send purchase-information, server-side just call HTTP request(POST and GET) with pre-defined attributes(client_id, client_secret, grant_type).

It means there is no login process anywhere.

In addition, the `client_id` and `client_secret` I use seemed created in google-developer-console by create-credentials in below image but not when registering APP.

[image]

---------- Edit ----------

I tried to recreate `client_id` with an owner account. the screenshot is from `google developer console->IAM&Admin->IAM`

[image]

However, it is still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The current user has insufficient permissions to perform the requested operation."

The user you have currently authenticated with no longer has access to the data you are trying to access.  Either give the user access again or login with a user that does have access.

**ClientId**

When you wish to work with a Google API you must register your application.  When you do so google gives you a client id.  This identities your application to google when ever it runs.

**Accessing User data**

To access private user data you must have permission of the person who owns the data to access it.   Your application runs (Denoted by the Client id) the user is prompted to login to google and grant your application consent to access their data.

If the user looses access to the data that they have granted your application access to your application will loose its access.

Comment: Thank you for your asnwering. you mean that user who created the client_id no longer has authority? and who do you mean `login with a user that does have access` how, where?

Comment: When you run your application.  It probably requested that you login with a google account and accept consent.  The user you logged in with no longer has access this has nothing to do with a client id.

Comment: I describe more detail. Please check it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It doesnt matter if it was done server side.  Some user authenticated it at least once or you are using  a service account.   If you are using a service account then someone removed its access grant it access again and it will work.  Again this has nothing to do with the client id this has to do with the user you are logging in with that has access to the data.

Comment: Ok, It is not about `client_id` but who authenticated the `client_id` and if the user who authenticated the `client_id` no longer has relevant permission now, the permission error will happen. right?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but please check my edited question.